# meaning of infrastructure services

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I m reading How to: Register and Use Services from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921149.aspx). But I dont understand meaning of Infrastructure services. What is that? In Article says:

> •In the Bootstrapper class. In the Bootstrapper class, you usually
>   register infrastructure services for application startup or services
>   that are consumed by multiple modules.
>  •In modules classes. In
>   modules classes, you usually register services consumed by a
>   particular module. However, you are not restricted to this; you can
>   also register services consumed by other modules.

Can you give me a simple example what it means?

I mean can I register my service in bootstrapper which works for any other modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infrastucture Service is a service which is very basic and common which is used by almost all modules of your application.
for e.g, you have an application which requires some data to be used and manipulated by some modules for updating there UI using this data. let us call this data as ApplicationData so you can write a service called ApplicationDataService which will have properties required by all the Modules to update there UI.

```
        public class ApplicationDataServices : IApplicationDataServices
        {
         public ApplicationDataServices()
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// property for company name
           /// </summary>
           public List<string> CompanyNames { get; set; }

          public List<Color> Name{get;set;}
          ...
          ...
        }
```

in the bootstrapper.cs

```
           protected override void ConfigureContainer()
           {
               base.ConfigureContainer();
                IApplicationDataServices applicationData = new ApplicationDataServices();
                applicationData.Initialize();
                Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IApplicationDataServices), "ApplicationDataService", applicationData);
            }
```

first register these services and then you can resolve them and use them in any module of your application.